# "All vertices of a convex pentagon are lattice points, and its sides have integral length. Show that its perimeter is even."

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices, pythagorean-triples

"All vertices of a convex pentagon are lattice points, and its sides have integral length. Show that its perimeter is even." - Problem Solving Strategies, Arthur Engel, pg. 27.

I have proven the theorem through two methods. I thought about a third method, but it appears faulty, since it shows that the theorem is false. Please indicate me where I have made the error.

Consider two vertices of the pentagon. Since the points are in a lattice, and the sides are integers, $\Delta x , \Delta y, d \in \mathbb{N} \ $ . It is also obvious that $ \Delta x^{2}+\Delta y^{2}=d^{2} $.

That means that those three integers form a Pythagorean triplet.
$\therefore d$ is odd, which applies to all sides.

Since the perimeter is the sum of all sides,

$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
p = \sum\limits_{i=1}^5 d_{i}\\
\forall d_{i}, 2\nmid d_{i}
\end{array}
\right\}\Rightarrow \text{$p$ is odd.}
$

I can't seem to find the mistake. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pythagorean triplet $a^2+b^2=c^2$ need have $c$ odd only if it's primitive i.e. if we ignore cases like $6^2+8^2=10^2$.  Why should that be true here?

Comment: That is one careless and awful mistake to make. Thank you.

Comment: So, combining this observation with the fact that the perimeter is even, we have the corollary that at least one of the sides of a pentagon on a lattice must correspond with a non-primitive Pythagorean triple.

Comment: So where does the condition that the pentagon must be convex come in to the proof?

Comment: @DilipSarwate In the proof provided in the book, it is necessary for the pentagon to be convex. But assuming we have A,B,C vertices of the pentagon, A connected with B and B with C, we could draw all the points in the lattice which would render a solution for a point connected with A and with C (and since B is one of them, we have at least one solution). Thus, the points would be symmetrical about the AC line. Since B is on one side, we could draw B' on the other side. So I guess that you ARE right, and convexity isn't necessary.

Comment: @Théophile: Quite so. It makes me wonder about the following, which I think I'll put up as a question: At most, how many of the five sides of an integral pentagon can correspond to primitive Pythagorean triples?

Comment: @Semiclassical You can get four such edges (let's call them *good*) easily enough. Starting from the origin, draw any good edge, and then draw another good edge from there. Reflect those about the $y$-axis to get two more good edges; we now have four. Finally, join the two loose ends to get a horizontal edge. This last edge is bad (as we knew it must be) since its triple is of the form $(2k,0,2k)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of sharing this, I've found a 3rd method that works for any lattice polygon. Place one vertex at $0$ and let the sides be represented by the vectors $a_1, \dots, a_n, -a_1-\dots-a_n.$ The perimeter is $\sum\limits_i ||a_i|| + ||\sum\limits_i a_i|| \equiv \sum\limits_i ||a_i||^2 + ||\sum\limits_i a_i||^2 = 2\sum\limits_i ||a_i||^2 + 2\sum\limits_{i < j} \langle a_i, a_j \rangle \equiv 0 \mod 2.$